# -y in Linux for example dnf -y install samba

Tags: linux, options, dnf

what does the -y mean in linux. this symbol is always used after a command for example dnf -y install httpd.

Everywhere I have looked I cannot find a definite answer. Please help

Comment: Rely on your man pages. Type `man dnf` (or man find, or whatever) and read away. the command line options (like -y) are listed one by one, often in alphabetical order, with a description of its functionality. Some commands even have an EXAMPLES section at the bottom to get you started.

Comment: Oh yeah, hit `q` to exit when you're done

Answer (score 1):

The `-y` switch confirms that you want to download and install the package that you've specified whether it's `samba` or anything else.

If you don't use `-y` then you'll see a message with the last line being:

```
Is this ok [y/N]:
```

Using `-y` will automatically answer `y` so that you don't have to type it in.

Answer (score 1):

If you have such questions, there are a few reflexes you can learn:

## help section

type `dnf --help`, for most programs you will get a help section explaining all options. In this case:

> -y, --assumeyes       automatically answer yes for all questions

## man pages

type `man dnf`. Many programs provide man(ual) pages explaining how to use the program and its options. Here we also find:

> ```
>    -y, --assumeyes
>           Automatically answer yes for all questions
> ```